# I would like to search my own question, even though somebody has deleted it

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, search

Some time ago, I have asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1777135), and the comments contain the information I was looking for.
Later on, that question has been deleted by somebody else.

Now I would like to be able to search for that question (in order to find the information in the comments), but that seems not to be possible:

- When launching a search (search string `user:547147 "od"`, meaning my own questions about the `"od"` command), deleted questions are not shown.
- The "Advanced Search Tips" don't give me the possibility to enable search for deleted questions.

(As I am not the one who has decided to delete that question,) I would like it to be possible to find it back in a search.

Is that possible?

Comment: Deleted questions are not shown in search results. If you like to ask for the feature to be added then you may need to ask at https://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: Question was deleted because it wasn't modified once it was closed. Since the question was not improved, which means it cannot be undeleted, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Zfa.png) is a list of the comments.

Comment: I should clarify my last comment, the question could be improved and undeleted, I just don't foresee that happening.  Which is the reason I took a screenshot of the comments and linked to it.  Since I cannot in good faith vote to reverse the deletion of the question in it's current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching your own deleted posts is only possible when the user has [access to moderator tools](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege on 10k rep.

> You also have a new search operator available to find your own deleted posts: `deleted:1`.

Aside from that, users can only browse their deleted questions on https://superuser.com/users/deleted-questions/current